# How to enable debugging of flex sdk code in intellij flex module

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea

When I debug the flex application in IntelliJ Idea(v 13), it seems that it doesn't use the debug flex rsls. Stack traces don't contain line numbers, breakpoints are not working, etc.

'Generate debuggable swf' is checked and custom code is debuggable.

How to fix that issue and enable debugging of sdk code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like compiler uses `.swz` which are signed Adobe RSLs and cannot be debugged. I suggest for debug purposes not to use Flex RSLs. You can set this option in **Dependencies/Framework linkage - Merged into code**.

Another option is to set compiler option `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true`

Or you can change `*.swz` RSLs in **{FLEX_SDK}/frameworks/flex-config.xml** to `*.swf` RSLs (make sure they exist).

Comment: Unfortunately first two options don't work. Changing flex-config.xml solved the problem.